# Xamarin.forms long running background work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin platform. I'm developing an application for all three major platforms (WP,iOS,Android) using Xamarin.forms. 
How can I sync data with my server in the background -> I need something similar to Android Service. I want to sync the data even when the user goes to a different screen of the app. It would be great if I could continue syncing the data even when the user leaves the app.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the only solution i have found
http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/

in a few words:
You can't abstract background tasks in Xamarin.Forms because iOS, Android and WP works in a different way. You have to use MessagingCenter to send and receive data from specific implementations in each platform

Comment: Link no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

Have look to this article: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/

You could provably be interested in the Transfer Background tasks.

Regards

Comment: I'm looking for cross-platform solution, but I guess there is no such solution. Thanks for the tip.